# why can't I print a single tuple from a list?

Tags: python

I'm just trying to flip and print the first tuple in a list.
If I try this code I get error "cannot unpack non-iterable int object"

```
lst = [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]
for x,y in lst[0]:
    print(y,x)
```

However if I make this simple edit, it works fine. why can't I print a single tuple from a list?

```
lst = [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]
for x,y in lst[:1]:
    print(y,x)
```

Comment: Why are you iterating?

Comment: Because in `lst[0]` you index list by integer which returns single element however in `lst[:1]` you index list by slice which returns list that you can iterate over.

Comment: `print(lst[0][1], lst[0][0])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to flip first element would be to:

```
lst = [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]
print((lst[0][1], lst[0][0])) # -> (1, 'a')
```

However reason why your code throws error here is because you try to iterate over element instead of list, where element is `('a',1)` by iterating over it first value is `'a'` and you try to split it into 2 variables `x` and `y` which throws an error.

```
print(type(lst[0])) # -> <class 'tuple'>
for x,y in lst[0]:
    print(y,x)
```

Here if we iterate over list `[('a',1)]` (because we used slice as list index instead of integer) first value is indeed `('a',1)` and we can split it into `x` and `y` variables without errors.

```
print(type(lst[:1])) # -> <class 'list'>
for x,y in lst[:1]:
    print(y,x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your list:

```
lst = [('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]
```

The first element of the list:

```
>>> lst[0]
(1, 'a')
```

Then when you iterate over this, you are asking to unpack *each element*. It would be like writing

```
for x, y in 1:
    # do something
for x, y in 'a':
    # do something
```

Wth `lst[:1]`, you are *slicing* the list, and getting a list of tuples back.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to loop through the first element of the list. 
Just unzip the first element and print:

```
x, y = lst[0]
print(y,x)
```

or in a loop:

```
for x, y in lst:
    print(y, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a loop there. `lst[0]` is the tuple you want to flip, there is no need to iterate.

```
x, y = lst[0]
print(y, X)
```